# Error Axios: Recibe url tipo undefined cuando debería de ser string

Tags: nodejs, typescript, axios

gracias por entrar a la pregunta.

El error que obtengo es que al realizar una petición de axios obtengo el error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

He estado viendo que hay issues abiertos con el tema en Github: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4407

Tal y como indica gente del issue he realizado downgrade de la dependencia en mi package.json, tenía la versión 0.25.0 (la cual teóricamente ha recibido un fix), he probado con 0.24.0 y con 0.21.1 (versiones con las cuales anteriormente el mismo código funcionaba correctamente, verificado en los commits).

Mi código actualmente tiene esta pinta:

```
 /*La variable env se recibe en la función, únicamente aporta el nombre del entorno
al que apunta, vease staging1 o staging2 --> También he probado a realizar
la petición SIN el uso de la variable pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.*/

    const url_token = `https://subdomain.${ env }.myhost.com/token`;

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        url: url_token,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {},
        auth: {
            username: client_id!,
            password: client_secret!
        },
        data: {},
    };

    return await axios(config).then((res: any) => { 
        return `Bearer ${ res.data.access_token }` 
    });
```

Realizo un `console.log(typeof(config.url))` para verificar que efectivamente no mando un string. Pero parece que estoy mandando el valor correcto.

En la versión más reciente de axios (0.25.0) obtengo el error siguiente:

```
Error: Provided config url is not valid
```

Adjunto los logs de error completos:

**v0.25.0:**

```
   throw new Error('Provided config url is not valid');
          ^

Error: Provided config url is not valid
    at Axios.request (C:\xxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:40:11)
    at wrap (C:\xxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\bind.js:9:15)
    at getData (C:\xxxxxxxxxx\build\src\helpers\insertion\4p.data.js:34:41)
    at data_ (C:\xxxxxxxxx\build\src\helpers\insertion\index.js:25:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

**v0.24.0 / 0.21.1**

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
    at Url.parse (node:url:169:3)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (node:url:156:13)
    at dispatchHttpRequest (C:\xxxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:118:22)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at httpAdapter (C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:48:10)
    at dispatchRequest (C:\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:58:10)
    at Axios.request (C:\xxxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:108:15)
    at wrap (C:\xxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\bind.js:9:15) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

En ambos casos el error está en la url de la variable config de axios. He probado a cambiar "url" por "baseURL" tal y como indica la documentación: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro | https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig

¿Alguien se ha enfrentado a este issue? Desconozco que estoy haciendo mal.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

**UPDATE**

La petición que intento realizar puedo ejecutarla vía Postman sin problemas, pero el código que ofrece Postman para NodeJs - Axios tampoco funciona para ninguna de las versiones indicadas.

¿Puede ser algún tema de caché? Es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: No se si la línea de `url_token ` la pusiste solo para ilustrar, pero ¿Cómo puede ser que una variable `env` vaya en el medio del dominio? ¿Podrías pones tu estructura real? ¿`xxx.xxx.xxx.com`?

Comment: Buenas @JaimeMenéndez la variable env representa los distintos entornos preproductivos y de produccion (se diferencian únicamente por una parte de la url) Añado la estructura

Comment: Es un dominio válido, lo utilizo vía postman y llevo con este proyecto más de un año sin problemas con la url. No pego la url exacta por temas de seguridad empresarial. Espero encontrar solución, estoy planteando un cambio de librería...

Comment: ¿ @JaimeMenéndez por qué no te parece que tenga un formato correcto la url?

Comment: Mis disculpas. No siempre se ven `Multi-Level Subdomains` y olvidaba que eran válidos. La estructura clásica es `subdomain` + `domain`. ¿Has probado usando `fetch`? Puedes instalártela en nodejs y funciona como en el navegador.

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste que `url_token` es de tipo string? `console.log(typeof url_token)`

Comment: @g.4 si, pero nada, sigo obteniendo que es undefined.